# Symfony 4 - Retrieve src from image into a variable to send in database

Tags: javascript, php, image, twig, src

I have a page on which there is a slide that shows one image among all the ones that are stored in my images/avatar folder.
This slide is html and javascript coded.

This is my page.html.twig (only the slide and form part)

```
<div class="app-character_creation-center">
<div class="app-avatar-slider">

    <button class="app-avatar-slide-btn-left app-nav-btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>

    <img class="app-avatar-slide-img" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/001.png') }}" alt="avatar001">
    <img class="app-avatar-slide-img" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/002.png') }}" alt="avatar002">
    <img class="app-avatar-slide-img" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/003.png') }}" alt="avatar003">
    <img class="app-avatar-slide-img" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/004.png') }}" alt="avatar004">
    <img class="app-avatar-slide-img" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/005.png') }}" alt="avatar005">

    <button class="app-avatar-slide-btn-right app-nav-btn" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<div class="app-form app-form-character_id">
    {{ form_start(idForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(idForm) }}
    <button class="app-nav-btn app-form-btn" type="submit">CONFIRM</button>
    {{ form_end(idForm) }}
</div>
```

And this is my page.js

```
    let slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    let i;
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName("app-avatar-slide-img");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Now I want to catch the displayed image's src url into a php variable so I can send it with a form that is on the same page. I don't know how to get that information into my php controller.

Comment: You'll need to attach a `submit` event to the form with javascript and inject the current displayed image URL in the form with like a hidden input in order to send it back to the controller

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you